# Cython pxd "cimport XXX as YYY" leads to "YYY.pxd not found", even though "cimport XXX" works

Tags: python, python-2.7, cython, distutils, cythonize

The title almost explains everything.

I'm trying to cimport a module with

```
cimport myMinExPkg.someModule.base as someModuleBase
```

and then using the "someModuleBase" alias like

```
someModuleBase.BaseClass
```

but this results in an error

```
myMinExPkg/someModule/baseExt.pxd:7:5: 'someModuleBase.pxd' not found
```

I don't know why Cython is looking for this pxd file. If I rename the alias to the same name as the file it works, e.g.

```
cimport myMinExPkg.someModule.base as base
```

or just

```
cimport myMinExPkg.someModule.base
```

and using them appropiately. But that is of course not the point, it should work either way in my opinion.
I tried searching SO and google, but only found solutions to obvious mistakes I don't think I'm making.

**--------------------------------------------------------------------------**

Additional information:

My folder structure looks something like this

```
├── myMinExPkg
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── someModule
│       ├── base.c
│       ├── baseExt.c
│       ├── baseExt.pxd
│       ├── baseExt.pyx
│       ├── base.pxd
│       ├── base.pyx
│       ├── __init__.py
├── setup.py
```

setup.py file

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
from Cython.Build import cythonize

ecadef = ["-O1", "-Wunused-but-set-variable"]
iddef = ["/usr/local/include/", "./myMinExPkg","/usr/local/lib/"]


extensions = cythonize([
                        Extension('myMinExPkg.someModule.base',
                            sources=['myMinExPkg/someModule/base.pyx'],
                            extra_compile_args = ecadef,
                            include_dirs = iddef
                            ),
                        Extension('myMinExPkg.someModule.baseExt',
                            sources=['myMinExPkg/someModule/baseExt.pyx'],
                            extra_compile_args = ecadef,
                            include_dirs = iddef
                            )
                        ])


setup(name = 'myMinExPkg',
      packages = ['myMinExPkg', 'myMinExPkg.someModule'],
      package_data={'myMinExPkg': ['*.pxd'], 
                    'myMinExPkg.someModule': ['*.pxd']},
      cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
      ext_modules = extensions
     )
```

Comment: Are you tried it with py3.5?

Comment: No I haven't. But it should be more of a Cython problem and not a Python problem anyway...